# How to exclude junit.framework.TestCase from being intercepted by Bytebuddy's @Origin

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, byte-buddy

I am trying to run JUnit4 tests during execution and then intercept the tests with Bytebuddy (version 1.2.3) to figure out what methods in the test are mutator methods (change a variable in the underlying class). The whole process is working fine with normal JUnit tests, but when I try to execute the exact same tests but extending junit.framework.TestCase, the process crashes. I managed to restrict the error to the following: when I try to debug, I get many entries saying `clazz="junit.framework.testcase"` (see Interceptor.java), which is the class that causes the crash.

My question is the following. How can I exclude the TestCase class from being intercepted? I tried it with the following statements:

1. `ElementMatchers.not(ElementMatchers.namedIgnoreCase("junit.framework.testcase"))`
2. `ElementMatchers.not(ElementMatchers.is(junit.framework.TestCase.class))`
3. `ElementMatchers.not(ElementMatchers.nameContains("junit.framework"))`

With the following code, I try to receive as console output:

```
intercepted: tests.producttest
running testSquarPrice
intercepted: example.product
finished testSquarPrice
```

but the result is always the following output, even with my attempts to exclude `junit.framework.testcase`:

```
intercepted: junit.framework.testcase
intercepted: junit.framework.testcase
intercepted: junit.framework.testcase
intercepted: junit.framework.testcase
intercepted: junit.framework.testcase
intercepted: junit.framework.testcase
intercepted: junit.framework.testcase
intercepted: junit.framework.testcase
intercepted: junit.framework.testcase
intercepted: tests.producttest
running testSquarPrice
intercepted: example.product
finished testSquarPrice
intercepted: junit.framework.testcase
```

Here is my code:
Starter.java

```
import introspect.Agent;

public class Starter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Agent x = new Agent();
        x.run();
    }
}
```

Agent.java

```
package introspect;

import org.junit.runner.Request;

import net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType.Builder;

public class Agent {

    public Agent() {
    final Interceptor interceptor = new Interceptor();
    new AgentBuilder.Default()
            .type(ElementMatchers.not(ElementMatchers.named("junit.framework.testcase"))
                    .and(ElementMatchers.nameStartsWithIgnoreCase("example")
                            .or(ElementMatchers.nameEndsWithIgnoreCase("test"))),
                    ElementMatchers.not(ElementMatchers.isBootstrapClassLoader()))
            .transform(new AgentBuilder.Transformer() {
                @Override
                public Builder<?> transform(Builder<?> builder, TypeDescription arg1, ClassLoader arg2) {
                    return builder
                            .method(ElementMatchers.isPublic()
                                    .and(ElementMatchers.not(ElementMatchers.isDeclaredBy(Object.class))))
                            .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(interceptor).filter(ElementMatchers.named("intercept")));
                }
            }).installOn(ByteBuddyAgent.install());
}

    public void run() {
        JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();

        Request request = Request.method(ProductTest.class, "testSquarPrice");
        junit.run(request);
    }
}
```

Interceptor.java

```
package introspect;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.AllArguments;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Origin;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.RuntimeType;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.SuperCall;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.This;

public class Interceptor {

    @RuntimeType
    public Object intercept(@Origin Method m, @SuperCall Callable<?> zuper, @AllArguments Object[] args,
            @This Object thiz) throws Exception {

        // get the name of the intercepted class
        String clazz = m.getDeclaringClass().getName().toLowerCase();
        System.out.println("intercepted: "+clazz);

        return zuper.call();
    }
}
```

ProductTest.java

```
package tests;

public class ProductTest extends TestCase{

    @Test
    public void testSquarPrice() {
        System.out.println("running testSquarPrice");

        Product p = new Product();

        int re = p.squarPrice(10);

        assertTrue(re == 100);

        System.out.println("finished testSquarPrice");
    }
}
```

Product.java

```
package example;

public class Product {

    public int count, price, index;

    public Product() {
        index = 0;
    }

    public int squarPrice(int price) {
        index++;
        return price * price;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By `ElementMatchers.not(ElementMatchers.is(junit.framework.TestCase.class))`, you are only excluding the class itself. You are not excluding methods that are declared by this class and which are inherited by other classes. What you want to do is probably more like:

```
method(ElementMatchers.isPublic()
  .and(ElementMatchers.not(ElementMatchers.isDeclaredBy(Object.class))))
  .and(ElementMatchers.not(ElementMatchers.isDeclaredBy(TestCase.class))))
```

or even like:

```
method(ElementMatchers.isPublic()
  .and(ElementMatchers.isDeclaredBy(arg1)))
```

In the later case, you only intercept declared methods but never override methods that are inherited.

Comment: Thank you a lot. The first solution worked perfectly, and the second one might be helpful in the future.